# JQuery Fine Uploader S3 uploadsuccess params on file size

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Need a little help on pass the upload file size variable to the endpoint (the php controller). I tried multiple ways, but seems the method is not working.

First of all, I am not be able to get upload file 'id' which is necessary for getSize function.

Secondly, system through errors when I put getSize function in the parames: object. 
part of my code below:

```
var loader=$('#fine-uploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
      ... ...       
     //deleted not relevant code above 
   uploadSuccess: {
    endpoint: "/s3/uploadSuccessful",
    customHeaders: 
        {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},

    params: {
              user_id:'{{Auth::user()->id}}', // there are params I want to 
              lot_id: '{{$lot->id}}',         //pass to the controller 
                                              //no issue. the php controller
                                              //got them. this code is part of 
                 .. ...                       //Laravel blade.
             size: function (){
                     return  this.uploaderMethods.getSize('0');
           //hard code file id 0 for test. not working.
```

Or I have tried: `size: function (){
                         return  this.getSize('0');`

Or  `size: $('#fine-uploader-s3').fineUploaderS3('getSize', '0'),`

None of them works. Thanks for any help here.

Comment: Got the solution:   Forget about fine-uploader library passing the size variables. in the controller once I get the S3 file $key from the js call back I can use that in Laravel Storage  to obtain the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in the docs using [setUploadSuccessParams](https://docs.fineuploader.com/api/methods-s3.html#setUploadSuccessParams).  Add a callback block such as below:

```
callbacks: {
                onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
                    var size = this.getSize(id);
                    var newParams = {"size": size};
                    loader.setUploadSuccessParams(newParams, id)
                }
            },
```